# Is there always a small geodesic parallelogram?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, geodesic

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a surface, and $p_1$, $p_2$, $p_3$, $p_4$ $\in$ $S$.

If $p_1$, $p_2$, $p_3$ and $p_4$ are close enough, we can define $\gamma(p_i,p_j)$ as the trace of the unique geodesic passing through $p_i$ and $p_j$.

Now define (if possible) $R_{p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4} \subset S$ as the region (an open and  connected set) whose  boundary satisfies

$$\partial R_{p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4} = \gamma(p_1,p_2) \cup \gamma(p_2,p_3) \cup  \gamma(p_3,p_4) \cup \gamma(p_4,p_1).$$

An image to help  understand the definition above
[image]

> I would like to know if given $p$ $\in$ $S$ and $\varepsilon>0$,
>   there always exist $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4$ $\in$ $\Sigma_p (\varepsilon)$,
>   such that $p \in R_{p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4}$ ?
>
> Where $\Sigma_p (\varepsilon)$ is the geodesic ball centered in $p$
>   with radius $\varepsilon$.

Comment: For the conditions you name, yes. No reason to expect control on the vertex angles.

Comment: I will change the name for "geodesic region" I think that geodesic square was a bad definition name

Comment: @WillJagy Do you know how I prove this?

Comment: Depends on your background. A small enough geodesic ball, (disc for a surface), is geodesically convex: every pair of points is joined by a unique geodesic that remains entirely within that neighborhood.

Comment: @WillJagy But we can't (always) write the geodesic disk in the form $R_{p_1, p_2, p_3,p_4}$

Comment: But you can always find a such a parallelogram inside the disk. Choosing the $p_i$ to be the corners of a small enough square centred on the origin in geodesic normal coordinates should do the job.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I think that the image of the edges of the square are not geodesics (using normal coordinates), because we only garantee that  the radial lines are geodesics.

Comment: Which is why I said to use the corners of the square as your points, not to use its edges.